# How to get a de-duplicated list of row labels and their summed values in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with multiple rows in this format:

```
Column A|Column B
label   | value
--------|--------

header (merged cells)
labelA  |12
labelB  |5
labelC  |9

header (merged cells)
labelA  |13
labelD  |8
```

It's basically a list of labels and values split up over multiple different sections. In reality there are 70-80 labels and all labels are used 5-10 times. I need to create an output on a separate sheet in the following format:

```
Column A|Column B
label   | Total sum
--------|----------
labelA  |25
labelB  |5
labelC  |9
labelD  |8
```

Ideally the first sheet can be dynamically updated, with new labels reflecting immediately in the second sheet.

I'm sure I can create a macro to accomplish this, however I don't want to add macros if I do not have to. The data is not currently in a pivot table.  Is there any way to accomplish this without those solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the sum for the different labels is easily achieved using a `SUMIF` formula. Assuming your labels are in Column A of your output sheet, with the first label being in row 2, the formula for `B2` would read:

```
=SUMIF(SourceSheet!$A:$A,$A1,SourceSheet!$B:$B)
```

– extend as needed. Getting all labels automatically is slightly trickier as you need to de-duplicate them. The following [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) will do that for the labels in rows 1 to 100 of your source sheet (adjust the scope as needed, replacing `SourceSheet` by the correct sheet name):

```
=IFERROR(
   INDEX(SourceSheet!$A1:$A100,
     SMALL(
       IFERROR(
         IF(
           MATCH(SourceSheet!$A1:$A100,SourceSheet!$A1:$A100,0)<ROW(),
           "",
           MATCH(SourceSheet!$A1:$A100,SourceSheet!$A1:$A100,0)
         ),
       ""),
     ROW())
   ),
 "")
```

**Note this belongs on a single line in Excel** (I’ve indented the formula here to make it a bit more readable) **and that for it to work, you need to save it as an array formula** (select the whole range you want your results in, input the formula in the formula bar – not in the cell! – and save it with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>).

If the formula has been input correctly, starting with values like these:

[image: Source Sheet screenshot]

will return these results:

[image: Destination sheet screenshot]

As you can see, this will return your source sheet header rows too. They can probably be filtered out, but without details as to their exact contents, I can’t tell you how.

Comment: Well that's just awesome.  It's a shame I just wrapped up a big ole macro, but I'm saving this for later.  Hopefully future Googlers come across this!

Comment: @Whetstone: that is what Ask Different is there for :).

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is to pivot it and once you add new data, just refresh the table. If you really don't like pivots, you can use [sumif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) or [sumproduct](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumproduct-function-HP010342935.aspx?CTT=1). Before you make the formula, set name ranges for your columns. It will be easier when you create the formula in another sheet.

```
=sumif(ColumnA, "labelA", ColumnB)
```

ColumnA & ColumnB will be the names of your ranges. It's just a sample

```
=sumproduct((ColumnA="labelA")*(ColumnB))
```

As for new labels, you can manually add them in the second sheet. I don't know how to add them automatically unless you make a macro. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the [`sumif`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx) function. To total everything for `labelA`, use this function:

```
=sumif(Sheet1!A1:A9999, "labelA", Sheet1!B2:B9999)
```

You would need to add a function manually for each new label. I am not sure how to automatically add a total for a new label.

Comment: After investigating for about an hour I couldn't come up with anything and am now waist deep into creating a macro.  Not the ideal solution in my books, but deadlines are deadlines.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Whetstone: For a formulaic solution see my answer (took a bit of time to test and write up).

Comment: That is only half an answer. See my solution for the other half :).